# embedded with / embedded in

Tags: grammar

Example ([Why Is Putin Sending Troops to Syria?](http://www.newsweek.com/why-putin-sending-troops-syria-368436)):

> Weiss refers to “compelling evidence that Russians have **embedded with** the Syrian military.” Assad recently told Hezbollah’s TV station that “We have strong confidence in the Russians, as they have proven throughout this crisis, for four years, that they are sincere and transparent in their relationship with us,” and he appears to be right.

I don't understand why it is not *embedded in*? They're actually supposed to be embedded IN the Syrian military if what the author is trying to say is that Russians have become part of Syrian regiments. It almost sounds like Russians have embedded together with the Syrian military in something, but it just doesn't say what that something is. What do you guys think?

Comment: Oxford dictionary mentions **embed with**, but in the sense of [Attach (a journalist) to a military unit during a conflict](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/embed). Note the "(a journalist)" part. One of the given examples is *'The only exceptions are journalists embedded with US military units, a practice that many fear skews the reporting of the war.'* This seems like an extended use of that definition, because the word *Russians* in the news doesn't appear to be journalists. So, whether this use is standard is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see from [this example](https://books.google.com/books?id=UQtLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA291&dq=%22embedded%20with%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCGoVChMIg6iE6MjdxwIVg1w-Ch0j1QoI#v=onepage&q=%22embedded%20with%22&f=false) (1838) about shells *embedded with* fossil bones, the stative meaning (are embedded with) has been around since at least the early 19th century.

The reflexive meaning (embed itself, embed oneself, embed themselves) with the preposition "in" is also [attested from the 19th century](https://books.google.com/books?id=EbJfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA69&dq=%22embedded%20themselves%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAjgUahUKEwjc9NT0yt3HAhXJaz4KHdEBAgg#v=onepage&q=%22embedded%20themselves%22&f=false).

The modern reflexive usage, with the preposition "with", is an extension of that older reflexive meaning, the change of preposition reflecting the fact that the entity doing the incorporating is not a substance (mud, clay, fossil stratum) but a human group, such as the military.  There, "with" might be paraphrased "among".

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a *special* case when the context is journalism.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/embedded)

> a journalist who is embedded ***with*** a military unit or a political campaign.

OxfordDictionaries

> The only exceptions are journalists embedded ***with*** US military units, a practice that many fear skews the reporting of the war.

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/embedded)

> Western journalists are all embedded ***with*** the attacking US forces.